# confusion on little endian big endian

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have some confusion on little endian/big endian. Seems I am missing
smth simple. Some feedback appreciated.
For example, say we have two functions which retrieve least and most significant bytes of
32bit value:

```
#define LSB(x) ((x) & 0x000000FF)

#define MSB(x) ((x) & 0xFF000000)
```

My question is: do above two functions return correct result *both* on *big* endian and *little* endian machines?

Now  I will explain why I have the confusion.
Imagine we are on a little endian machine. On a little endian machine integer 9 is stored in memory like this (in hex): 09 00 00 00 (least significant byte first)
Now at some point, you might think, if we use above LSB function, then we would end
up with such expression: 09 00 00 00 & 00 00 00 FF which is 0 - but of course that's not how above LSB function will work eventually. So it seems I am missing smth. Any help appreciated.

Also if I say `int y = 0x000000FF` - this is 255 regardless of the endiannes of the machine right?

Comment: OT: Shouldn't it be `#define MSB(x) (((x) & 0xFF000000) >> 24)` or just `#define MSB(x) ((x) >> 24)` (assuming a 32bit value is passed)?

Comment: You might want `MSB(x) = ((x) >> 24)`, otherwise code like `if (MSB(x) == 0xFF) ...` won't work.

Comment: ok I will look into that but for now I was not particularly concerned with best implementation of LSB and MSB functions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regardless of endianness, `x & 0xFF` will give you the least significant byte.

First of all, you should understand the difference between endianness and significance. Endianness means in what order the bytes are written to memory; *it's completely irrelevant to any computation in the CPU*. Significance says which bits have a higher value; *it's completely irrelevant to any system of storage*.

Once you load a value from memory into CPU, it's endianness doesn't matter, since to the CPU (more accurately, ALU) all that matters is the significance of the bits.

So, as far as C is concerned, `0x000000FF` has 1s in its least significant byte and `and`ing it with a variable would give its least significant byte.

---

In fact, in the whole C standard, you can't find the word "endian". C defines an "abstract machine" where only the significance of the bits matter. It's the responsibility of the compiler to compile the program in such a way that it behaves the same as the abstract machine, regardless of endianness. So unless you are expecting a certain layout of memory (for example through a `union` or a cast of pointers), you don't need to think about endianness at all.

---

Another example that might interest you is shifting. The same thing applies to shifting. In fact, like I said before, endianness doesn't matter to the ALU, so `<<` always translates to shift towards more significant bits by not even the compiler, but the CPU itself, regardless of endianness.

---

Let me put these in a graph with two orthogonal directions so maybe you understand it better. This is how a load operation looks like from the CPU's point of view.

On a little-endian machine you have:

```
         MEMORY            CPU Register

  LSB BYTE2 BYTE3 MSB  ---->   MSB
    \    \     \----------->  BYTE3
     \    \---------------->  BYTE2
      \-------------------->   LSB
```

On a big endian machine you have:

```
         MEMORY            CPU Register

      /-------------------->   MSB
     /    /---------------->  BYTE3
    /    /     /----------->  BYTE2
  MSB BYTE3 BYTE2 LSB  ---->   LSB
```

As you can see, in both cases, you have:

```
CPU Register

    MSB
   BYTE3
   BYTE2
    LSB
```

which means in both cases, the CPU ended up loading the exact same value.

Comment: please look at the paragraph where I am explaining why I had the confusion, maybe that will more clear out to you as to which part of the question actually I am most confused. (e.g., the place where I talk about 09 00 00 00 & 00 00 00 FF)

Comment: @dmcr_code, I have already addressed your confusion. The fact is that `0x0000009` is stored in **memory** as `09 00 00 00`, but the **ALU** still sees it as `0x0000009`. There is no such thing as endianness for the ALU, only significance. When you load/store registers to memory, the endianness is taken care of, but that's _only_ a matter of storage, not processing.

Comment: Think of a RAID system for example. The data is stored in pieces between hard disks, but that's just a detail of storage. All applications would see the data coherently because the underlying system takes care of storing and restoring the data. It's the same thing with endianness. It's a matter of how the CPU expects the data to be laid out in memory, but beyond the process of storing/restoring data in memory, there's no such thing as endianness.

Comment: Ok, so what you basically mean is that even though on little endian system 9 is stored in memory like this: 09 00 00 00, when I will pass it to the actual LSB macro, it will already be interpreted as number 0x000009 - that's what you mean right?

Comment: @dmcr_code, that's exactly right. During processing, storage doesn't matter. So if your number is `0x00000009`, even if the memory stores it as [sigil of baphomet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_of_Baphomet), it's still `0x00000009` and `and`ing it with `0x000000FF` will give you `9`.

Comment: yes, basically so even if in memory 09 00 00 00 is stored, when this value will be **loaded** it will be interpreted correctly and obtain value of 9 right? (assuming we are on a little endian machine). And 0x000000FF is always 255 - because that is how we write that right? Big endian way

Comment: @dmcr_code, exactly. We "store" numbers on paper from left to right. If some strange country writes numbers from right to left, then `90000000` would still be `9`, right? ;) It's the same with storing in memory.

Comment: Ok, yes I see we write in a big endian way, so when we hardcode value"0x000000FF" to the compiler, it interprets it as **we** humans do, in a big endian way?

Answer (score 3):

`0x000000FF` is always 255, regardless of endianness. It is *stored* as `FF 00 00 00` on little endian machines, so `LSB(9)` will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these work correctly regardless of endianess.

Both the number you use as the mask and the number you give these as input have the same endianess, so they give the same result either way.

Endianess becomes an issue primarily when you have (for example) an integer you've received over a network connection as an array of `char`s. In such a case, you have to put those `char`s back together in the right order to get the original value.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: do above two functions return correct result both on big endian and little endian machines?

Yes, they do. The problem comes when you want to form a scalar from a multi-byte array which is not what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you treat the integer value as a single entity and not as a sequence of raw bytes (in memory, on the wire etc), the issue of endianness will not feature in your code.

Thus, `0x000000FF` is always 255 and your `LSB` and `MSB` macros are correct.

Comment: it seems I am confused about smth else. That part i have explained in paragraph where I talk about 09 00 00 00 & 00 00 00 FF .. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Endian is about how memory is used.  You primarily have to worry about it when serializing or deserializing bytes to memory, storage or a stream of some kind.

I believe your macros will sometimes work and sometimes not work as expected depending on how you use them.  If x is an int (assuming you are using 32 bit  ints) then you should be fine since the compiler knows what an int is and how it is represented when x is not a 32bit number you could run into problems.

Comment: good point about size of parameter, although the question is something else